# Zip code validation in magento 2

Tags: magento2, validation, user, zipcode

In checkout page I try to add validation for postal code.

I already find a list with javascript validation for magento 2 here [validation rule](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/356) and I found this rule "validate-zip-international "but I don't know where to apply this rule. 
In magento 1 you can add your javascript class in input class on billing.phtml.
Does anyone know what it's in Magento 2?

Now by defaul if a type a wrong postal code it only tell me that my code is wrong, and i can pass over this step(like in the next screen-shot)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add validation on the zip field we should overwirte `Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`  and add this code :

```
 <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="zip-range" xsi:type="string">true</item>
</item>
```

`zip-range` for example is a already defined rule in `rules.js`.

We can overwrite this rule js according to our needs in this location:`Theme\Theme\Magento_Ui\web\js\lib\validation\rules.js`